# Rollover the logfile everyday irrespective if any messages is getting logged or not

Tags: java, logging, log4j, rollingfileappender

I have below configuration in my log4j.properties

```
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR,FA
log4j.appender.FA=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FA.RollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy
log4j.appender.FA.RollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=.\\logs\\app.log-%d{dd-MM-yyyy}
log4j.appender.FA.File=.\\logs\\app.log
log4j.appender.FA.layout=org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout
log4j.appender.FA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %p %t %c: %m%n
log4j.appender.FA.Append=true
```

There are days when no error is reported and file is not getting rolled at the next consecutive days till next error is reported. *As appender is set to ERROR level it will not roll log file till some error message is reported* .

My question is **Can we develop some mechanism so that the file will be rolled every midnight irrespective if appender have some error messages to be logged or not ?**

I have a java application and we are using log4j api for logging so solution in Java or Log4j both would be appreciated .

thanks in advance

Note:- I cannot set the logger level to Info/Debug because of the size constraint

Comment: So you want empty log files on the days that nothing happens?

Comment: unfortunately yes .. this is the requirement   . Actually we send the yesterdays logs to another system where it expect the the logFileName in app.log.dd-MM-yyyy and they want it everyday (if there is file is missed for a particular day then it is throwing an error).

Comment: I'm not sure Log4j can do this. What do you use to send the files? Could that system not create the files if they are missing?

Comment: basically its a client requirement to see the logs . so they have developed some code(which we really don't know) and we are sending them the file through email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is a log4j behaviour not to rollover the empty file we have to use below approach

1. Have a written a thread and scheduled it for 12 hours which logs the dummy statement "This is a dummy message"
2. As the file is not empty now hence log4j takes care of rollover

and We send the log files every day we have decided to log a dummy statement after every 12 hours saying "This is a dummy message" , which has solved the problem of rollover.

Answer (score 1):

Using the new `CronTriggeringPolicy` in Log4j 2.5, I found a solution without dummy lines, which I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32378201/in-log4j2-how-to-configure-renameemptyfiles-to-be-false-for-the-rollingfile-app/34791646#34791646). Unfortunately, it still requires some custom plugin code because the behaviour of the `DefaultRolloverStrategy` is to simply delete empty files.